# PLS-00103 in a Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER comprobarHora 
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON PEDIDOS 
    FOR EACH ROW
declare
    v_data int(4);
    v_dia varchar(20);
begin 
    select to_char(sysdate,'hh24mi') into v_data from dual;
    select to_char(sysdate, 'day') into v_dia from dual;

    if ((v_data BETWEEN (2031, 0830)) OR (v_dia='saturday') OR (v_dia='sunday')) then
        raise_application_error(-20001,' No hi ha estoc');
    end if;
end;
```

Can someone help me with this,error information is about line 8.

/

Comment: Why are you putting an explicitly character value into an integer field?  Declare `v_data` as `varchar2(255)` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is on line 8 of the PL/SQL section (not the entire statement), which is:

```
if ((v_data BETWEEN (2031, 0830)) OR (v_dia='saturday') OR (v_dia='sunday')) then
```

That isn't how [the `BETWEEN` condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm) is specified, it should be:

```
if v_data BETWEEN 2031 and 0830 OR v_dia='saturday' OR v_dia='sunday' then
```

But that still won't work as the lower value has to come first ("If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty"). You aren't handling the time going past midnight anyway. You could either test:

```
if v_data >= 2031 OR v_data <= 0830 OR v_dia='saturday' OR v_dia='sunday' then
```

or swap the `BETWEEN` conditions and negate it:

```
if NOT (v_data BETWEEN 0830 and 2031) OR v_dia='saturday' OR v_dia='sunday' then
```

As Gordon Lindoff pointed out, you're storing a string in a numeric field, so you're doing an implicit conversion. If you want to keep the 'time' as a number you should convert it explicitly really. You should probably also be making sure you get the day name back in the language you expect, using [the third parameter to `to_char`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm); and the day name is padded by default, so using the abbreviation is simpler.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER comprobarHora 
    BEFORE INSERT 
    ON PEDIDOS 
    FOR EACH ROW
declare
    v_data int(4);
    v_dia varchar(20);
begin 
    v_data := to_number(to_char(sysdate,'hh24mi'));
    v_dia := to_char(sysdate, 'dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');

    if v_data >= 2031 OR v_data <= 0830 OR v_dia='sat' OR v_dia='sun' then
        raise_application_error(-20001,' No hi ha estoc');
    end if;
end;
/
```